# ng-repeat inside ng-repeat creates empty td element - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've a little odd problem when using two ng-repeat for objects which contain arrays. Here is the Angular HTML-Code:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="reqs in requirements | orderBy:['categoryOrder','order']">
    <td>
        <strong>{{reqs.category}}</strong>
    </td>
    <td data-ng-repeat="values in reqs.values | orderBy:'showOrder'">
        <div data-ng-repeat="(key,value) in values">{{value}}</div>
    <td>
</tr>
```

The table will be displayed fine and the data also looks fine. My only problem is, that after each tr an empy td element will be insert without any class and I can't get rid of it. Here is the outputted HTML:

```
<tr class="ng-scope" data-ng-repeat="reqs in requirements | orderBy:['categoryOrder','order']">
    <td>
        <strong class="ng-binding">Foobar</strong>
    </td>
    <td class="ng-scope" data-ng-repeat="values in reqs.values | orderBy:'showOrder'">
    <td class="ng-scope" data-ng-repeat="values in reqs.values | orderBy:'showOrder'">
    <td class="ng-scope" data-ng-repeat="values in reqs.values | orderBy:'showOrder'">
    <td> </td>
</tr>
```

Does anyone else has experienced this kind of odd behaviour? The td element is completely empty and doesn't even has a class attribute assigned to it. Here is the object I'm using:

```
category: "Foobar"
categoryOrder: 10
description: "Some desc"
id: 2
order: 10
shortName: "SM-01"
values: [
0: {Foo: "Bar", showOrder: 1},
1: {Bar: "Foo", showOrder: 2},
2: {Meh: "Mah", showOrder: 3}
]
```

I'm using AngularJS 1.3.0. Any help is appreciated, as this is driving me nuts :).

Ares

Comment: can you please create a fiddle on this

Comment: Please take the time to format your code. Reading html without corrects indents is nearly impossible.

Answer (score 4):

missing closing tag `<td>` instead of `</td>`

don't worry.. we've all been there

Answer (score 2):

You arent closing your td in your second td